# Android : requestFeature() must be called before adding content, where is the error?

Tags: android, libgdx, admob

I would like to add a ad banner with AdMob in my android game, using LibGDX nd google play services...

Could you pleas help me to fix this error ? Can't figure why it don't work... :/

I know what this error means, but i don't really know with what it's linked in my code...
(I'm new to java and android dev, and french, so it's quite hard for me... >.< )

```
03-19 17:34:13.523: E/AndroidRuntime(5806): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 17:34:13.523: E/AndroidRuntime(5806): Process: com.louu.aimproject, PID: 5806
03-19 17:34:13.523: E/AndroidRuntime(5806): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.louu.aimproject/com.louu.aimproject.MainActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
03-19 17:34:13.523: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2227)
03-19 17:34:13.523: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2277)
03-19 17:34:13.523: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
03-19 17:34:13.523: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
03-19 17:34:13.523: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-19 17:34:13.523: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-19 17:34:13.523: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5088)
03-19 17:34:13.523: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 17:34:13.523: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-19 17:34:13.523: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
03-19 17:34:13.523: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
03-19 17:34:13.523: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-19 17:34:13.523: E/AndroidRuntime(5806): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
03-19 17:34:13.523: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:303)
03-19 17:34:13.523: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.app.Activity.requestWindowFeature(Activity.java:3332)
03-19 17:34:13.523: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at com.louu.aimproject.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:62)
03-19 17:34:13.523: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5434)
03-19 17:34:13.523: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-19 17:34:13.523: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2181)
03-19 17:34:13.523: E/AndroidRuntime(5806):     ... 11 more
03-19 17:41:44.643: E/dalvikvm(6652): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView', referenced from method com.louu.aimproject.MainActivity.onCreate
```

Code

```
@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    gameHelper.setup(this);
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    View gameView = initializeForView(new TutorialLibgdxGameservices(this), false);
    AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-7435783642832057/7018436522");
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    //.addTestDevice("")  // Mon téléphone est un nexus 5
    .build();
    layout.addView(gameView);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    layout.addView(adView, adParams);
    setContentView(layout);
}
```

Please help, I don't know what I should change.

Comment: see also the [Libgdx + Admob tutorial](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx)

Comment: This tuto is outdated, I'm desesperatly searching for help everywhere, or an example to understand...

Comment: the tutorial was last updated 4 days ago...

Comment: Well, so i'm definitly weak...
Could you please help me ?
I think I need something more human to help me to understand the things I haven't with only the different tuto...

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is:

```
Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView', referenced from method com.louu.aimproject.MainActivity.onCreate
```

This means that the com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView class has not been added to your APK. The class is contained in the Google Play Services library, so make sure that it is added to your project.

Comment: I will try it tonight, but I have to write again the whole prog... U_u
(Failed a save)...